# Implement custom add method to Java

Tags: java

I have a code that has `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` and would like to implement a custom add method class that I can use for both cases.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(anotherList);

LinkedList<Integer> listTwo = new LinkedList<Integer>();
listTwo.add(newList);
```

I would like to log for every add method for both LinkedList and ArrayList.

I would have thought implementing Java list interface would be sufficient. Is there a recommended approach of doing this?

I understand there are multiple ways of solving this thing.

Comment: You can certainly override methods and implement those interfaces, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by using both?  Arraylist and Linkedlist are fundamentally different data structures - the former is a contiguous block of memory, and the latter is disjointed.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by " deals with both cases" ?

Comment: *both cases*... as in ?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh what do u mean can u elaborate further?

Comment: It means your question as it stands is not clear enough to answer - add more detail, perhaps an example, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you haven't yet.

Comment: @pvg updated with some examples

Comment: You can simplify this a fair bit by just not using `LinkedList` and then wrapping just `ArrayList`. Subclassing `AbstractList` and including the arraylist by composition is probably best since that gives you guarantees about what methods are implemented in terms of your methods.

Comment: You might want to look into "JavaFX" and look into "Listeners" and "Properties."  You should be able to create a custom class with properties that you can add into the lists of your choice, as well as have a listener that will react and log each even as it happens, with the proper list being mentioned.  You might also be able to override the above by creating List<Integer> list = new ArrayList... and List<Integer> list2 =..... and manipulate the List interface, but it doesn't seem to be a good idea, and might not work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to include Guava as a dependency then it has a ready-made solution for delegating the default collections: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#forwarding-decorators

The example listed matches your example use-case:

```
class AddLoggingList<E> extends ForwardingList<E> {
  final List<E> delegate; // backing list
  @Override protected List<E> delegate() {
    return delegate;
  }
  @Override public void add(int index, E elem) {
    log(index, elem);
    super.add(index, elem);
  }
  @Override public boolean add(E elem) {
    return standardAdd(elem); // implements in terms of add(int, E)
  }
  @Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    return standardAddAll(c); // implements in terms of add
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there vanilla Java way to do this?

Comment: Only creating your own of `List` that delegates all methods (including equals/hashCode) to an underlying List.

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted you :) Is there a good example where I can find vanilla Java implementation?